# Manually patching an offline Windows 10 Enterprise install

Tags: windows-10-v1809

I apologize if this is too general, very new here.  I'm also an Instrument Engineer, not an IT professional, but I have been handed the ball, so I am asking the fine people here for an assist.  If I should post some other way or place, please may I ask for guidance?

I have to maintain a completely air-gapped Industrial Control System (ICS) which is now using Windows 10 Enterprise IOT LTSC version 1809. I can find the Cumulative Update file, plus the SSU Update file.

The installation uses Microsoft Defender AV so I presume I need to source definitions updates. I believe I have found these in the update catalog.

May I ask if there are any other security, functionality, or other patch files I should be looking to source that are purely OS-related? I am working with application suppliers separately for their updates.

Comment: Truly the best way (given the complexity of all the cumulative patches) is to hook it up each 6 months, update it, and then disconnect it.

Comment: @John - In some cases that is legally not possible.

Comment: @Tim - My suggestion is to NOT use Windows Defender, do a commercial AV, and download signature updates weekly/monthly manually.  It’s difficult to patch a offline system without a WSUS which is connected to the internet.

Comment: I do not think it is illegal to use Internet. I guess that depends on where you are.

Comment: @John - I have one particular system at work, where it would be illegal for me to connect it to the internet, due to the sensitivity of the data contained on it.  So the system is patched, while offline, much as an ICS would be required to do.

Comment: @john - I apologize for the exceptionally late reply - workload!  Sadly  I accept the complexity argument, but as this is an ICS within a highly sensitive CNI application, there simply is no internet connectivity option.  I can't say any more sadly.  However, it MUST be manually updated or not updated at all, and that for me is a non-option

Comment: @Ramhound - I agree with you, but my Client makes that choice not me, so hands are formally tied sadly...